# pythonにてopenpyxlでNoneを削除・置換

Tags: python, excel

下記のxlsxのデータを読み込みメールで送信したいですが、
テキストを取得する際にxlsxに空白があるため'None'が表示されます。
次の方法でNoneを置換してみましたが、'None'が表示されます。
どう直せばよいのでしょうか。

code部分

```
message = ''
for row in ws["A1:C4"]:
  for col in row:
    s2 = message.replace('None', '')→Noneが表示されたら、空白として表示したい
    message += f'{col.value}\n'
```

xlsxのデータ

```
 A       B     C         
アメリカ 1234個  66.7%　 
カナダ　 1234個　4.9%
　 　　　1234個　5.9%
日本　　 1234個　3.9%
```

code全体部分

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string
from smtplib import SMTP
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import smtplib
import codecs
import pandas as pd
import math
import glob

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(copyfile,data_only=True)
ws = wb.worksheets[10]

#件名
c2 = ws['Q5'].value
c3 = ws['Q10'].value
c3 =" ""¥""{:,}".format(c3)

#件名
text_c="【test"
text_d="個"
text_e="】"
fusion_2= str(text_c)+str(c2)+str(text_d)+str(c3)+str(text_e)
print(fusion_2)

##
message = ''
for row in ws["A1:C4"]:
  for col in row:
    s2 = message.replace('None', '')→Noneが表示されたら、空白として表示したい
    message += f'{col.value}\n'
    
message2 = ''
for row in ws["B1:C25"]:
  for col in row:
　　s3 = message.replace('None', '')
    message2 += f'{col.value}\n'

account = "1234"
password = "1234"

to_email = "1234"
from_email = "1234"

subject = fusion_2
#'\n'.join(values)
message += '\n'+message2
print(message)
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["Subject"] = subject
msg["To"] = to_email
msg["From"] = from_email

# メール本文
message = MIMEText(message)
msg.attach(message)

# 添付ファイルの設定

file_screen='C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\'
files = glob.glob(file_screen + " テスト*.jpeg")
print(files)


for file in files:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        file_data = f.read()
        file_name = f.name
        basename = os.path.basename(file_name)

        attach_file = {'name': 'テスト.jpeg', 'path': 'テスト.jpeg'} # nameは添付ファイル名。pathは添付ファイルの位置を指定
        attachment = MIMEBase('image', 'jpeg')

        file = open(attach_file['path'], 'rb+')
        attachment.set_payload(file.read())

        file.close()
        encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
        attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=basename)
        msg.attach(attachment)

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(account, password)
server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

わかる方いらっしゃいましたらご教示願います。
お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「次の方法でNoneを置換してみましたが、'None'が表示されます。」とは、すべての'None'がそのままなのでしょうか？一部の'None'が置換されずに表示されるという意味でしょうか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。下記の方法できました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

セルが空の場合、col.valueは`None`を返します。`"None"`という文字列ではありません。

`None`を`f'{col.value}'`で文字列化した後に、文字列置換で`"None"`を消す、というロジックはセルに`"None"`という文字列が含まれていた場合にも削除されてしまいます。明らかなバグですが、特定データのときにしか起きないのでわかりにくいやつです。あと、単純に処理が無駄です。

```
for row in ws["A1:C4"]:
  for col in row:
    if col.value is None:
      message += '\n'
    else:
      message += f'{col.value}\n'
```

のようにして「セルが空白でないときのみセルの値を結合する」という処理にするとよいでしょう。

(↑改行文字を見落としていたのでリライトしました)

またmetropolisさんのコメントのとおり、4行のifを1行にまとめて書いてしまうことができるような記法もあります。

Comment: おそらくメールを受信した側で、そのテキストを基に別のexcelに集計してそうな雰囲気なので、単に飛ばしてデータそのものを無くすとレイアウトが崩れるかもしれません。データが無い時は改行だけにする方が良さそうです。

Comment: f-string 内では式が使えるので `message += f'{"" if col.value is None else col.value}\n'` としても良いでしょうね。

Comment: みなさんいつも回答ありがとうございます。こちらも参考いたします。

Answer (score 1):

単に変換した処理結果は`s2`/`s3`に入れているのに、メール送信に使っているのは変換していない`message`/`message2`だからでしょう。

また、`for`ループの中の変換と追加の処理は逆にするか、変換処理は`for`ループを抜けた後、1度にまとめて行い、結果はそれぞれ`message`/`message2`に代入すれば良いのでは？

Comment: 上記で試したら問題なく置換されました。全然気づきませんでした。ありがとうございます。